# AC servo position flight surface control system

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, current, transformer, transmitter

So if a control transmitter is used to set the Pilot's input command signal and a control transformer is used to compare this desired position to the current position and produce an error signal. My question is how does the feedback system work for this? How does the control transformer get the current position? Does it have something to do with its shaft? Quite unsure about this

Comment: From the way you describe things, I surmise that what you call a "control transformer" is actually a resolver, which is type of shaft angle sensor that is basically a transformer in rotary form. The rotation changes the coupling between the windings. https://www.dynapar.com/technology/encoder_basics/resolvers/

Comment: That said, this question is too vague.

Comment: @BeatriceUK: This is a duplicate of your earlier question.  The wording is different, but its really the same question.  You would do better to improve the first question than to post a slightly different new question.